# How to make angular material <md-card> expandable?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm displaying dynamic content by looping with `md-card` tags. What I want to achieve is to show additional information when clicking on an `md-card` by expanding it like an accordion.

Has anybody already tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use md-item/md-card

```
  <md-item ng-repeat="user in users" class="item"
         ng-class="{ 'selected-item': $index == selectedUserIndex}">
        <md-item-content class="user tile md-whiteframe-z1"
                         ng-class="{ 'selected md-whiteframe-z2': $index == selectedUserIndex}"
                         layout="column">
          <div layout="row" layout-fill ng-click="selectUserIndex($index)" class="folded">
            <div class="md-tile-left">
              <img ng-src="{{ user.face }}" class="face">
            </div>
            <div class="md-tile-content" layout="column" layout-align="center start">
              <h3>{{ user.name.first + " " + user.name.last }}</h3>

              <p ng-hide="$index == selectedUserIndex">
                <span>Something</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <md-divider layout-fill ng-show="$index == selectedUserIndex"></md-divider>
          <div layout="column" layout-fill class="expanded">
            <span>some content</span>
            <br/>
            <span>some content</span>
            <br/>
            <span>some content</span>
            <br/>
            <span>some content</span>
            <br/>
            <span>some content</span>
            <br/>
            <span>some content</span>
            <br/>
            <span>some content</span>
          </div>
        </md-item-content>
        <md-divider class="divider-inset" ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
      </md-item>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ESm1xd6kRCZAupdPfet?p=info)**

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for :)